# Leap year calculation using logical operators

Tags: java

Can somebody explain the condition of the if statement?
I know what `&&` and `||` does, but now I don't understand how it calculates it correctly. I got it right by fluke, and I just want to understand why it does what it does.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Give year: ");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(lukija.nextLine());
        if (year % 4 == 0 && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 ) ) { 
            System.out.println("Year is leap year");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Year is not a leap year..");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PradeepSimha See the comment in the code

Comment: % is modulo divison. example 1 % 2 = 1, 2 % 2 = 0, etc. So it is the rest from divison of two numbers. Then the rest should be obvious.

Comment: Because it's like a smarter & and |?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the `if`

```
    //this one----//
if (year % 4 == 0 && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 ) )
```

determines if the year is actually a leap year. They occur each year after four years so that's why the first check verifies that the modulus of dividing the year by 4 is zero.

Then, the second part tests something similar every 100 years (not a leap year)

```
                      //Here ---------//
if (year % 4 == 0 && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 ) )
```

With an exception for every 400 years, when that year is actually leap year.

```
                                          //Here --------//
if (year % 4 == 0 && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 ) )
```

Long story short, this statement defines that the `year` variable represents a leap year when it can be fully divided by 4 but not by 100, except when it is also fully divisible by 400.

Comment: This is somehow what i wanted to know. I know that a year that is divisible by four is a leap year, how ever if it is divisble by 100 it has to be div by 400 also.

Answer (score 1):

```
year % 4 == 0 && ( year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 )
```

`year % k ==0` means that year is divisible by k.

Here, the evaluation follows a short circuit approach

In    `A && B`, B will be evaluated only if A evaluates to true else B is not evaluated

In `A || B`, B will be evaluated only if A is false else the result would have been true irrespective of the outcome of A.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `m % n == 0` it means, `m` is divisible by `n`.  The rest follows the definition for the Gregorian Calendar which is every 4 years (exact multiple), but not every 100 unless it is every 400. e.g. 2000 was a leap year. 2100 won't be.

This gives you a year which is 365.2425 days long on average.

Answer (score 0):

```
// divisible by 4
isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0);

// divisible by 4 and (divisible by not 100 or divisible by 400 (any one should be true))
isLeapYear = isLeapYear && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pseudo-code for the leap year calculation algorithm taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm):

```
if year modulo 400 is 0 then
   is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0 then
   not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0 then
   is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year
```

The condition is only doing the algorithm in one line using java `&&` and `||` operators and grouping the operands properly

Answer (score 0):

A [leap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) is any year that can be evenly divided by `4` except if it can can be evenly divided by `100`, except if it can be evenly divided by `400`. Modulo arithmetic is used here to check that the test year divides evenly into these 2 numbers.